# How to capture values from dropdown in JMeter

Tags: drop-down-menu, jmeter, html-select

For code like below:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 select-me show_me del_nxt" style="display: block;">
                <select class="prime" name="primary" id="primary" onchange="newsecondary(this)">
                      <option value="none" id="1200">---Select main---</option>


      <optgroup label="dummy1">
         <option value="abc-2-1">abc</option>
         <option value="xyz-2-1">xyz</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Dummy2">
         <option value="abc1-2-1">abc1</option>
         <option value="C1-2-1">C1</option>
         <option value="D1-2-1">D1</option>
      </optgroup>
   </select>
   <span class="Error"></span>
</div>
```

How to capture random value from dropdown list? thanks in advance.

Scenario is we have 4 drop downs with same type of html code as above.
Unless user selects any value from first drop down, another wont get enabled. this is how these 4 dropdowns are dependant on previous dropdown value .

Answer (score 1):

Since content is html, the most maintainable way is to use [CSS Selector Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) based on this [syntax](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

Configuration would be the following:

[image: CSS Selector]

Comment: above solution is not working, I am calling the variable as ${option} in the request but I see ${option} in sent request data.

Comment: where did you put the css selector extractor ?

Comment: added css selector extractor within request

Comment: I tested my answer with the response you show and it works, so I guess the response is maybe different. can you show it fully?

Comment: thanks UBIK finally it worked. Now, my first dropdown selects 1 input randomly but others donot select any yet. There is no response in response data, since the request doesnot have any response available.

Comment: it shows the input selected from value like "abc-2-1",xyz-2-1 but I wnt to pass value like abc,xyz,C1,D1, etc. How can we make specific to select it?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) added to your request.
With the Regular Expression:

```
option value="([a-zA-Z0-9])+"
```

To ectract random value you need to set `Match No` to `0` as shown below

[image]

You may test your RegExp here [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/4726m)
Read more about [Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to select a random value and forget - go for [HTML Links Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#poll_example)
2. If you need the selected value anywhere else - you can extract it using i.e. [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0), it allows executing arbitrary [XPath queries](https://www.google.com/search?q=w3schools%20xpath&oq=w3schools%20xpath&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2464j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

   - Get text of the `selected` option:

     ```
     //select/optgroup/option/@selected/parent::*/text()
     ```

     [image]
   - Get all options for [optgroup](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) with the label of `dummy1`

     ```
     //select/optgroup[@label='dummy1']/option/@value
     ```

     [image]
   - etc.

Comment: We have multiple labels and values in it, can you please refer above html and let me know how to get the xpath of it